# Default implementation for Debug/Display for structs that implement a local trait

Tags: rust

Let's say I have a trait that has a name() method:

```
pub trait Something {
    fn name() -> &'static str;
}
```

I would like to provide a default implementation for Debug and Display for everything that implements a particular local trait. I want debug/display to use a method on the local trait. I came up with two approaches but neither work.

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=84c1dc1d277f92b22ef15cbcc9c494e8)

I understand why approach 2 (supertrait with method) doesn't work so I won't include it here.

Approach 1 (pasted below) seems like it might be related to the orphan rule, except that it is a local trait for the bound. It seems like there ought to be a way to do this.

```
pub trait Something: std::fmt::Debug {
    fn name() -> &'static str;
}
impl<S:Something> std::fmt::Debug for S { // Error: type parameter `S` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", S::name())
    }
}
struct Test1 {}
impl Test1 {
    fn name() -> &'static str { "TestA" }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't implement a trait I don't own for all types that implement a trait I do own](/q/43989065/2189130) You can't implement external traits on external types. There is some [wiggle room for generic traits](/q/75765502/2189130), but that isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

As for approach 1: Consider what happens if you add the following impl:

```
impl Something for String {
    fn name() -> &'static str {
        ""
    }
}
```

[`String` itself implements `std::fmt::debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Debug-for-String), so it would conflict with `impl<S:Something> std::fmt::Debug for S` (where `S` can be substituted by `String`)

What should Rust do here? Rust decided to forbid the scenario.